# How do I retrieve a value in an object in powershell in my replace statement?

Tags: regex, powershell, replace

Trying to use an Object Map to replace a month name with the month number.
The use case, is that I'm trying rename files that include names of the month.

```
$monthNameToNumberMap = @{
  January = '01'
  February = '02'
  March = '03'
  April = '04'
  May = '05'
  June = '06'
  July = '07'
  August = '08'
  September = '09'
  October = '10'
  November = '11'
  December = '12'
}

Write-Host "Desired : 02 20 => ";
"February 20" -Replace '([A-z]{3,9}) (\d{2})', "$monthNameToNumberMap[`$1] `$2"

Write-Host "Desired : 05 03 => ";
"May 03" -Replace '([A-z]{3,9}) (\d{2})', "$monthNameToNumberMap[`$1] `$2"

# receiving : @{January=01; February=02; March=03; April=04; May=05; June=06; July=07; August=08; September=09; October=10; November=11; December=12}[February] 20
```

I'm failing to access the Object Map's value using the regex match group.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to evaluate the backreference value inside a string replacement pattern, which is impossible. You need to define a callback and pass it to the `[regex]::Replace` method:

```
$regex = [regex]'\b([A-Za-z]{3,}) (\d{2})\b'
$callback = {  param($m) $monthNameToNumberMap[$m.Groups[1].Value] + " " + $m.Groups[2].Value }
$regex.Replace("February 20", $callback)
```

Note that `[A-z]` [matches more than just letters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29771901/why-is-this-regex-allowing-a-caret/29771926#29771926), hence, it is advisable to use `[a-zA-Z]`.

I also added word boundaries to avoid matching strings like `AAAAAAAAAA 2222222222222222`.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for answering, when I try to use this I only get " 20" as the return.
I can't see why though, could you check for me ?

Comment: @InkhSuTesou See my screenshot

Comment: In v5 I took out `\s` and it returns the result you want

Comment: @trebleCode `\s+` matches 1 or more whitespaces. Why take it out?

Comment: I know, but I got the same result OP did when copy/pasting from your answer so I'm not sure why it works without it

Comment: Ok, let it be a space then, same as in the original pattern.

Comment: hey, @trebleCode answer works in my powershell, but you answered it correctly, I just believe his is more compatible.  Please update your answer with his fix.  so that I can mark this as the answer.  Thank you very much both.

Answer (score 1):

here's a somewhat different way to do the job. [*grin*] it uses the built in `.MonthNames` list to convert the month name to a number.

if you need this to be culture-invariant, you can use `[System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo]::InvariantInfo.MonthNames` instead of the `Get-Culture` list.

```
$DateStringList = @(
    'February 20'
    'January 3'
    'August 14'
    'June 19'
    )
$MonthNameList = (Get-Culture).DateTimeFormat.MonthNames

foreach ($DSL_Item in $DateStringList)
    {
    $MonthName, [int]$DayNumber = $DSL_Item.Split(' ')
    $MonthNumber = $MonthNameList.IndexOf($MonthName) + 1
    'Source date  = {0}' -f $DSL_Item
    '{0} is month # {1}' -f $MonthName, $MonthNumber
    'Numeric date = {0:D2}/{1:D2}' -f $MonthNumber, $DayNumber
    '=' * 20
    }
```

output ...

```
Source date  = February 20
February is month # 2
Numeric date = 02/20
====================
Source date  = January 3
January is month # 1
Numeric date = 01/03
====================
Source date  = August 14
August is month # 8
Numeric date = 08/14
====================
Source date  = June 19
June is month # 6
Numeric date = 06/19
====================
```

Answer (score 1):

[Wiktor Stribiżew's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54951336/45375) works in all versions of PowerShell.

In **PowerShell *Core*** (v6.1 and above) you now *can* solve the problem using `-replace`, namely by passing a *script block* as the replacement operand:

```
"February 20" -replace '\b([A-z]{3,9}) (\d{2})\b', { 
  $monthNameToNumberMap[$_.Groups[1].Value] + ' ' + $_.Groups[2].Value
}
```

`$_` inside the script block is the match at hand, as a [`System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.match) instance.
The script block's output is used as the replacement string.